# exception in msvcr110_clr0400.dll

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, server-explorer

I just unpacked my new laptop on Windows 8, and installed the latest version of Visual Studio Ultimate 2013.
Through the server explorer view I tried to add a new connexion to a sql-server database. (Connect to database button)

[image]

Each attempts to log-in finished by a crash of visual studio.

[image]

Then I tried to get more information about the issue using VS as a debugger for itself.
It seems that msvcr110_clr0400.dll thrown an exception.
[image]

Just in case here is the disassembly :
[image]

I tried and re-tried several times, checked for updates, installed an other version of vs (Ultimate2012).Any clue how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Require repair installation of .net 4.0 (or 4.5/4.5.1).